# How to make a custom child command automatically retry

Tags: coffeescript, cypress

I'm trying to use the following dual command as shortcut to find dom elements.

```
Cypress.Commands.add "el", prevSubject: "optional", (subject, id) =>
  if subject?
    subject.find("[data-cy=#{id}]")
  else
    cy.get("[data-cy=#{id}]")
```

The problem is that the command doesn't retry if the element I'm looking for needs a moment to appear.

All the following approaches work

```
cy.wait(1000)                           # wait for element to appear
cy.get("parent").el("mark")

cy.get("parent").find("[data-cy=mark]") # or type out what the command does

cy.el("mark")                           # or use the command as parent command
```

but just `cy.get("parent").el("mark")` doesn't wait for the element to appear and fails.

I get the same problem if I define the command as child command like this

```
Cypress.Commands.add "el", prevSubject: true, (subject, id) =>
    subject.find("[data-cy=#{id}]")
```

Is there a way to get my custom command to behave the same way as `find` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead

coffeescript:

```js
cy.wrap(subject).find("[data-cy=#{id}]")
```

javascript:

```js
cy.wrap(subject).find(`[data-cy=${id}]`)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is quite surprising, but I was able to verify your results.

The simplest work around I came up with (a bit of a hack) is to re-get the subject within the custom command.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('el_with_ReGet', {prevSubject: true}, (subject, id) => {
  const selector = subject.selector || subject.prevObject.selector;
  return cy.get(selector).find(`[data-cy=${id}]`)
})
```

---

Another option is to use the 3rd party [Cypress Pipe](https://github.com/NicholasBoll/cypress-pipe) instead of a custom command.

> cy.pipe can be used as a simpler replacement for Cypress Custom Commands - you just write functions.
>
> cy.pipe works very similarly to cy.then except for a few key differences:
>
> - pipe will try to document the function name in the Command log (only works on named functions)
> - pipe will create DOM snapshots to aid in debugging
>     If the function passed to pipe resolves synchronously (doesn't contain Cypress commands)
> - - AND returns a jQuery element, pipe will retry until the jQuery element list is not empty (most Cypress commands do this)
> - - AND is followed by a cy.should, the function will be retried until the assertion passes or times out (most Cypress commands do this)

```js
import 'cypress-pipe';

it('should find child by id by pipe (replacing custom command)', () => {

  const elFn = (id) => (subject) => subject.find(`[data-cy=${id}]`)

  cy.visit(...)

  cy.get('parent')
    .pipe(elFn('mark'))
    .then(result => {
      console.log('find result', result)
      expect(result.length).to.eq(1)
    })

})
```

---

There is a discussion here [Cypress.Commands.add needs option to force retry on that command #2670](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2670#issuecomment-445538293) with an example from Gleb Bahmutov using `cy.verifyUpcomingAssertions()` but it looks quite complicated.

This pattern worked ok when the test (eventually) succeeded, but I was unable to get it to stop retrying when the test failed (it should timeout, but I can't figure out how).

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. The hacky solution has the limitation that it doesn't work with `contains`, eg. `cy.contains('parent').el_with_ReGet('mark')` fails.

Comment: You can use it with `contains()` with a bit more hacking. The properties of `subject` inside the `reget` command seem to vary depending on the preceding command, to cover both `get` and `contains` the internal selector would be `const selector = subject.selector || subject.prevObject.selector;`. See update to the answer.

Comment: But the new version would fail with e.g `cy.contains(...).first(...)` - that's why it is hacky, you might need to adapt it depending on preceding commands.

Comment: It may be possible to put a looping construct into the `reget` commmand to cover all variations of preceding commands, but it would need to be tested thoroughly.

Comment: This is the basic problem with Cypress - the commands form a language of sorts, but there's not a formal definition so some combinations act in surprising ways. Another example is `cy.get(selector).contains(content)` vs `cy.contains(selector, content)`.